# Return nullable type in SQL Server function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

Is it possible to create a SQL Server function which returns a nullable string?

I would like to create a function which returns DBNull if the value is 0 or an empty string:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[SetDBNullNvarChar] (@input nvarchar(1000))
RETURNS (needs to be nullable)
AS
BEGIN
    if (@input = '' OR @input = 0) 
    BEGIN
    RETURN null
    END
return @input
END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any data type in SQL can be set to null unless a not null restriction is put on it. Therefore you should be able to use whatever return type best suits your needs...

In your calling code, you'd have to check to see if the returned value is equal to DBNull.Value and have your code act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking too much of C#, where you have to specify nullable types.

Comment: Is there a way to say `RETURNS <data type> NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

This does return `NULL` for me:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[SetDBNullNvarChar] (@input nvarchar(1000))
RETURNS NVARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    if (@input = '' OR @input = 0) 
    BEGIN
    RETURN null
    END
return @input
END

SELECT  [dbo].[SetDBNullNvarChar](0)
```

Comment: mhmm, for me it returns `NULL` but as a _string_. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @t3chbot because it says `RETURN NVARCHAR` in the function definition

Comment: so, this means that it is not possible to return a _reall_ `NULL` here?

Comment: @t3chb0t I don't understand your question. What exactly do you mean by "real null"?

Comment: I mean a `NULL` that is not `nvarchar` string with the text `'NULL'`; the value this returns is magically _casted_ to a text saying null, this means that for comparison you need to use the equal sign like `[Column] = 'NULL'` instead of `[Column] is NULL`

Comment: @t3chb0t the function in my answer will return `NULL` (not `'NULL'`) if you pass it `0` or `''`